# Error al declarar un método para ordenar

Tags: java, array, lista

En los métodos de ordenar estudiante necesito declarar el método de `Bubblesort` pero al declarar sus parámetros no me deja declarar método tipo `List`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("====    TestComparable    ====\n");
        java.util.List<Estudiante> estudiantes = generaDatos();
        System.out.println("Estudiantes:");
        imprimirDatos( estudiantes );
        ordenarEstudiantesASC( estudiantes );
        System.out.println("Estudiantes por promedio ( ASCENDENTE ):");
        imprimirDatos( estudiantes );
        ordenarEstudiantesDESC( estudiantes );
        System.out.println("Estudiantes por promedio ( DESCENDENTE ):");
        imprimirDatos( estudiantes );
    } // fin main


    private static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray) {
        int n = intArray.length;
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
         for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){
             if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]){
                //swap the elements!
                temp = intArray[j-1];
                intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
                intArray[j] = temp;
             }
          }
        }
    } // fin bubbleSort

    public static void ordenarEstudiantesASC() {

    }

    **public static void ordenarEstudiantesDESC() {
        bubbleSort(generaDatos());
    }**


    public static java.util.List<Estudiante> generaDatos() {
        java.util.Vector<Estudiante> personas = new java.util.Vector<Estudiante>();
        personas.add( new Estudiante("LORENA", 8.8) );
        personas.add( new Estudiante("JAIME", 9.1) );
        personas.add( new Estudiante("GABRIEL", 7.5) );
        personas.add( new Estudiante("AURORA", 9.4) );
        personas.add( new Estudiante("LETICIA", 8.9) );
        return personas;
    }


    public static void imprimirDatos( java.util.List<Estudiante> datos ) {
        for ( Estudiante e : datos ) {
                System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
    }
} // Fin de clase TestComparable


public class Estudiante implements Comparable<Estudiante> {
    private String Nombre;
    private double promedio;
    public Estudiante(String nombre, double promedio) {
        Nombre = nombre;
        this.promedio = promedio;
    }

    public double getPromedio() {
        return promedio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Estudiante [Nombre=" + Nombre + ", promedio=" + promedio + "]";
    }

    public int compareTo(Estudiante e) {
        if ( this.promedio < e.getPromedio() ) {
            return -1;
        } else if ( this.promedio == e.getPromedio() ) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return 1;
    }
} // Fin de la clase Estudiante
```

Comment: Tu método `bubbleSort` admite un arreglo de enteros `int[]` y tú quieres mandarle a ordenar una lista de `Estudiante`s `List<Estudiante>`, o al menos eso parece. Al parecer, deberías cambiar tu método `bubbleSort` para que soporte `List`.

Comment: gracias, pero ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: Por favor muestra más del diseño de tus clases.

Answer (score 1):

Según la edición de tu pregunta, parece que lo que necesitas hacer ahora es ordenar mediante método de burbuja una lista de elementos que son `Comparable`s. Para ello, debes primero cambiar la firma de tu método como sigue:

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort(List<T> lista) {
}
```

Donde:

- `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` significa: Definir un genérico `T` que es cualquier clase o interfaz que extiende de `Comparable`. Pero `Comparable` también recibe un genérico, el cual es `<? super T>` que significa `Comparable` de cualquier clase/interfaz que sea padre de la clase/interfaz `T` o el mismo `T`.
- `void` es el tipo de dato a devolver
- `bubbleSort` es el nombre del método
- `(List<T> lista)` son los argumentos del método, donde `List<T>` significa que se espera trabajar con una lista de elementos de tipo `T`. Este `T` está delimitado por las restricciones indicadas anteriormente.

Lo que sigue es adaptar el uso de una lista en lugar de un arreglo. Para el código de tu método, debes cambiar:

- Obtener elementos de la lista. En un arreglo, accedes directo con el índice, mientras que en una lista lo haces mediante el método `get`, de esta manera:

  ```
  //comentado porque esto es para arreglos
  //intArray[j-1]
  //nuevo código que funciona para listas
  lista.get(j-1);
  ```
- Modificar elementos de la lista. En un arreglo, puedes cambiar los datos directamente con el índice que necesitas, mientras que en una lista lo haces mediante el método `set`, así:

  ```
  //intArray[j-1] = ...
  lista.set(j-1, ...);
  ```

Por último, queda la comparación de elementos en la lista. Para comparar `int`, lo haces mediante `>`, `<`, `==`, etc. Para tu caso en particular, utilizas el resultado de [`Comparable#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-). Por ende, tu código cambiaría:

```
//intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]
lista.get(j-1).compareTo(lista.get(j)) > 0
```

Con esto en mente, tienes que reescribir el método `bubbleSort` apropiadamente. (No lo hago porque eso sería realizar el ejercicio por ti, y estaría haciendo tu tarea y así no aprenderías a programar).

Answer (score 0):

> En los métodos de ordenar estudiante necesito declarar el método de `bubblesort` pero al declarar sus parámetros no me deja declarar método tipo `List`.

Vamos a explicar la declaracion del metodo `bubblesort` para entender porqué:

```
private static void bubbleSort(int[] intArray) {
//             ↑               ↑ pide que le envies un array de ints 
//             ↑ no devuelve nada
```

Por tanto, cuando intentas esto:

```
java.util.List<Estudiante> estudiantes = generaDatos();
ordenarEstudiantesDESC(estudiantes);
```

Le estás intentando enviar una `List<Estudiante>` a un metodo que pide un array de `int`s.

---

Como parece que es un ejercicio academico, la solución que yo implementaria tiene varios cambios que simplemente presentaré para que intentes aplicarlos:

- El metodo `bubblesort` debe devolver un valor *(o bien estudiantes debe ser un atributo de la clase que contiene el main)*.
- Debe recibir una `List<Estudiante>`
- Debes comparar objetos `Estudiante`, no `int`o `doubles` ya que `Estudiante implements Comparable<Estudiante>`.

  **Por lo tanto:**

  ```
  private List<Estudiante> void bubbleSort(List<Estudiante>) {
      // crear nueva lista
      // iteracion a base de Iterator / bucle 
      // bubble sort... 
  }
  ```

**ADD ON:**

- Para poder hacer una ordenación de burbuja teniendo un objeto que implementa `Comparator` viene a ser simplemente `if(estudiante1.compareTo(estudiante2) < 0)`

---

**SOLUCION RAPIDA:**

Teniendo una lista, tienes las `Collections` de java que son geniales:

Ordenar ascendente:

```
Collections.sort(estudiantes);
```

Ordenar descendente:

```
Collections.sort(estudiantes);
Collections.reverse(estudiantes);
```

Comment: Desde Java 8, para ordenar descendentemente puedes ahorrarte las dos líneas y el rendimiento al utilizar [`Comparator#reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--)